# Mobile app outage?

Tags: support, ios-app

I am experiencing an issue with Stack Overflow mobile app:

[image: "No results. Try a different sort" message 1]

[image: "No results. Try a different sort" message 2]

Is this downtime or only at my end?

Comment: I currently have 0 results for my tag search as well. Not specific to mobile.

Comment: It appears keyword search is not working, neither in the main site, nor in Meta, nor in the Help Center.

Comment: [Search appears normal now](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+malloc).

Comment: Yes it’s back..

Comment: It’s back now, but appears to be very slow… and sometimes “Offline”.

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/982085564483633153