# Hello, complaints department? The search is broken

Tags: discussion, support, bug, search

[image: searching...]

No search results from API.  Outage persisting for 30 minutes or so in my area (Chicago).  +1 if you're affected by outage too.

I've tried to search for a similar post first, but ... you know ;)

Comment: [They know](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/982085564483633153). Probably the same cause as the [issue with the mobile app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365625/mobile-app-outage)

Comment: Likely API issue not mobile app issue.

Comment: been having issues with the search for chat and searches outside SO. figured it's a Network Wide issue

Comment: In my area (Brazil) search stopped working for some 10 minutes about an hour ago, then mostly returned to normal. Also, saving edits has sometimes been taking a lot longer than normal (I even got a couple timeouts).

Comment: [cross-site duplicate at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308795/165773)

Comment: How did you notice? Does anyone use the search anyway?

Comment: _[on hold]_ - how ironic